# Graph Theory Cartesian Product Example

Tags: graph-theory

Drawing the cartesian product of K4 and P3, K being a complete graph with 4 vertices and P being a path with 3 vertices.

Here is my take on it I was wondering if this is correct.

[My answer](https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-0/p280x280/16358551_10212563063374196_1135279506_n.jpg?_nc_ad=z-m&oh=8bbde384ed378f65b3c9196674a67783&oe=588E7AED)

Comment: Do not deface your questions, please.

Comment: Not sure how to remove it as the question has an expired URL?

Comment: I see. The image is no longer available. If you still have the file somewhere, you can upload it to `i.stack.imgur.com` using the tools. It might be findable on the wayback machine. If it can't be found any more, we'd have to think about what we could do. But editing the question to nonsense is not the right way.

Comment: No unfortunately not, it was on an old hard drive. I though editing to nonsense and flagging it would get rid of it. Not sure how to approach it in that case. I have another question with the URL expired as well if you check my profile. This question at least makes sense without the image but the other one is useless to anyone reading it.

Comment: You should better have raised a custom flag ("The image URL is dead. Should this question be deleted, or what else could be done?" or so). I've deleted the other question since that one is completely useless without the image. This one is at least still intelligible. I'm not sure what the best way to move on is. If you can recreate the image and upload it, that would be an option. In future, please use the site functionality to upload images to imgur, so that dead links to images won't be an issue (Stack Exchange has a contract with imgur to ensure that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is incorrect, some links are missing. What you did with $U_1$ and $W_1$ should also be done with vertices $V_1$ and $X_1$. It should be

[image]

Comment: You are correct, thanks!